# How to tell Firebug to skip debugging jquery.js

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

I've set a breakpoint in my javascript code and started to debug. At certain points, the debugger jumps into the linked jquery.min.js file and just stops. Is there any way to tell Firebug to skip certain files and stay in my code only?